# Ajax to update on database not work

Tags: ajax

I have a code that is supposed to receive from other apps an ajax call with points variable to update this variable on Database, but something is wrong.

This Is My Code:

The variable should work in points.

I have insert it on the query but it seems there is something wrong because it's not updated the database.

```html
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
 header("Location: index.php");
}



if(isset($_GET['points'])){

     //Lightly sanitize the GET's to prevent SQL injections and possible XSS attacks
    
     $points = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['points']));
     //$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `$db`.`scores` (`id`,`name`,`score`) VALUES ('','$name','$score');");
     $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET user_points = '$points' WHERE user_id = " . $_SESSION['user']);
  
  
}
     if($sql){
     
          //The query returned true - now do whatever you like here.
          echo 'Your score was saved. Congrats!';
          
     }else{
     
          //The query returned false - you might want to put some sort of error reporting here. Even logging the error to a text file is fine.
          echo 'There was a problem saving your score. Please try again later.';
          
     }
     
}else{
     echo 'Your name or score wasnt passed in the request. Make sure you add ?name=NAME_HERE&score=1337 to the tags.';
}

mysql_close();//Close off the MySQL connection to save resources.
?>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrryu.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkUGV.png)

Comment: and what is the error displayed? I mean, could you explain a little bit more?, Where is the ajax code / example of data / database or table structure?

Comment: well the error displayed is bitcoinrotator.publiadds.org.pt não consegue processar este pedido de momento.
500

Comment: Sorry but it is hard to evaluate with the information you are giving. That only tells that there is a server error but not what's the error...

Answer (score -1):

I Finally Solve The Problem...

```html
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
 header("Location: index.php");
}



if(isset($_GET['points'])){

     //Lightly sanitize the GET's to prevent SQL injections and possible XSS attacks
    
     $points = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['points']));
    //$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `publiadd_loginsx`.`users` (`points`) VALUES ('points');");
    $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET user_points = user_points +'$points' WHERE user_id = " . $_SESSION['user']);
 
  
  
     if($sql){
     
          //The query returned true - now do whatever you like here.
          echo 'Your Points was saved. Congrats!';
          
     }else{
     
          //The query returned false - you might want to put some sort of error reporting here. Even logging the error to a text file is fine.
          echo 'There was a problem saving your points. Please try again later.';
          
     }
     
}else{
     echo 'Your points wasnt passed in the request. Make sure you add ?name=NAME_HERE&score=1337 to the tags.';
}

// close MySQL connection 
mysql_close();
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<body bgcolor="#ffffff">
</body>
</html>
```

And This is work now really work